# Need help spotting my mistake in Python

Tags: python

For my class assignment we had to create a Python quiz that asks users to type capitals for states. Their video gave us the answer, but even typing it in as they have it displayed I keep getting an error and my program will not run. My professor is out until Monday, I am hoping someone in here can help me find my error. I am thinking I either have a misspelled word or a IDK... I have been staring at it for hours and line by line it looks the same as the example given.

Thank you for any help.

Here is my code:

```
# Constant for the number of states to quiz the user on.
NUM_STATES = 5

def main ():
# Initialize the state_caps dictionary.
state_caps = state_cap_dictionary ()

# Initial variables to keep count of the number
# of correct and incorrect answers.
correct = 0
incorrect = 0

#Quiz the user.
for count in range (NUM_STATES) :
     # Get a random entry from the dictionary.
     state, capital = state_caps.popitem ()

#Quiz the user.
print ('What is the capital of ', state, '? ', end=' ')
response = input ()

# Is the user correct?
if response.lower () == capital.lower ():
    correct += 1
    print ('Correct!')
else:
    incorrect += 1
    print ('Incorrect.')

#Display the results                
print ('Correct responses: ', correct)
print ('Incorrect answers: ', incorrect)


def state_cap_dictionary ():
  sc = { 'Alabama' : 'Montgomery' ,
      'Alaska' : 'Juneau' ,
      'Arizona' : 'Phoenix' ,
      'Arkansas' : 'Little Rock' ,
      'California' : 'Sacremento' ,
      'Colorado' : 'Denver' ,
      'Conneticut' : 'Hartford' ,
      'Delaware' : 'Dover' ,
      'Florida' : 'Tallahassee' ,
      'Georgia' : 'Atlanta' ,
      'Hawaii' : 'Honolulu' ,
      'Idaho' : 'Boise' ,
      'Illinois' : 'Springfield' ,
      'Indiana' : 'Indianapolis' ,
      'Iowa' : 'Des Moines' ,
      'Kansas' : 'Topeka' ,
      'Kentucky' : 'Frankfurt' ,
      'Lousianna' : 'Baton Rouge' ,
      'Maine' : 'Augusta' ,
      'Maryland' : 'Annapolis' ,
      'Massachusetts' : 'Boston' ,
      'Michigan' : 'Lansing' ,
      'Minnesota' : 'Saint Paul' ,
      'Mississippi' : 'Jackson' ,
      'Missouri' : 'Jefferson City' ,
      'Montana' : 'Helena' ,
      'Nebraska' : 'Lincoln' ,
      'Nevada' : 'Carson City' ,
      'New Hampshire' : 'Concord' ,
      'New Jersey' : 'Trenton' ,
      'New Mexico' : 'Santa Fe' ,
      'New York' : 'Albany' ,
      'North Carolina' : 'Raleigh' ,
      'North Dakota' : 'Bismarck' ,
      'Ohio' : 'Columbus' ,
      'Oklahoma' : 'Oklahoma City' ,
      'Oregon' : 'Salem' ,
      'Pennsylvania' : 'Harrisburg' ,
      'Rhode Island' : 'Providence' ,
      'South Carolina' : 'Columbia' ,
      'South Dakota' : 'Pierre' ,
      'Tennessee' : 'Nashville' ,
      'Texas' : 'Houston' ,
      'Utah' : 'Salt Lake City' ,
      'Vermont' : 'Montpelier' ,
      'Virginia' : 'Richmond' ,
      'Washington' : 'Olympia' ,
      'West Virginia' : 'Charleston' , 
      'Wisconsin' : 'Madison' ,
      'Wyoming' : 'Cheyenne' }
  return sc



main ()
```

Comment: The code you posted is not indented correctly, it won't work - fix that first. Also at the very least you need to provide the exact error message (including which line causes it) - which should usually tell you exactly what you need to fix

Comment: Thank you. I will work on the indenting now.

This is the error code I am getting right now:  

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/ryanraben/Desktop/State.py", line 31, in <module>
    print ('Correct responses: ', correct)
NameError: name 'correct' is not defined

Comment: Could you please indent the code? The reason for the error you are getting is most likely due to accessing a variable (`correct` in your case) which isn't defined in the current scope (inside a function, for example).

Comment: @LaurentH, `print` is perfectly capable of printing integers. And even if it wasn't, it would probably produce a ValueError or TypeError, not a NameError.

Answer (score 1):

With this indentation it works for me:

```
# Constant for the number of states to quiz the user on.
NUM_STATES = 5

def main():
# Initialize the state_caps dictionary.
     state_caps = state_cap_dictionary()

     # Initial variables to keep count of the number
     # of correct and incorrect answers.
     correct = 0
     incorrect = 0

     #Quiz the user.
     for count in range(NUM_STATES) :
          # Get a random entry from the dictionary.
          state, capital = state_caps.popitem()

          #Quiz the user.
          print('What is the capital of ', state, '? ', end=' ')
          response = input()

          # Is the user correct?
          if response.lower() == capital.lower():
              correct += 1
              print('Correct!')
          else:
              incorrect += 1
              print('Incorrect.')

     # Display the results                
     print ('Correct responses: ', correct)
     print ('Incorrect answers: ', incorrect)


def state_cap_dictionary():
  sc = { 'Alabama' : 'Montgomery' ,
      'Alaska' : 'Juneau' ,
      'Arizona' : 'Phoenix' ,
      'Arkansas' : 'Little Rock' ,
      'California' : 'Sacremento' ,
      'Colorado' : 'Denver' ,
      'Conneticut' : 'Hartford' ,
      'Delaware' : 'Dover' ,
      'Florida' : 'Tallahassee' ,
      'Georgia' : 'Atlanta' ,
      'Hawaii' : 'Honolulu' ,
      'Idaho' : 'Boise' ,
      'Illinois' : 'Springfield' ,
      'Indiana' : 'Indianapolis' ,
      'Iowa' : 'Des Moines' ,
      'Kansas' : 'Topeka' ,
      'Kentucky' : 'Frankfurt' ,
      'Lousianna' : 'Baton Rouge' ,
      'Maine' : 'Augusta' ,
      'Maryland' : 'Annapolis' ,
      'Massachusetts' : 'Boston' ,
      'Michigan' : 'Lansing' ,
      'Minnesota' : 'Saint Paul' ,
      'Mississippi' : 'Jackson' ,
      'Missouri' : 'Jefferson City' ,
      'Montana' : 'Helena' ,
      'Nebraska' : 'Lincoln' ,
      'Nevada' : 'Carson City' ,
      'New Hampshire' : 'Concord' ,
      'New Jersey' : 'Trenton' ,
      'New Mexico' : 'Santa Fe' ,
      'New York' : 'Albany' ,
      'North Carolina' : 'Raleigh' ,
      'North Dakota' : 'Bismarck' ,
      'Ohio' : 'Columbus' ,
      'Oklahoma' : 'Oklahoma City' ,
      'Oregon' : 'Salem' ,
      'Pennsylvania' : 'Harrisburg' ,
      'Rhode Island' : 'Providence' ,
      'South Carolina' : 'Columbia' ,
      'South Dakota' : 'Pierre' ,
      'Tennessee' : 'Nashville' ,
      'Texas' : 'Houston' ,
      'Utah' : 'Salt Lake City' ,
      'Vermont' : 'Montpelier' ,
      'Virginia' : 'Richmond' ,
      'Washington' : 'Olympia' ,
      'West Virginia' : 'Charleston' , 
      'Wisconsin' : 'Madison' ,
      'Wyoming' : 'Cheyenne' }
  return sc



main()
```

Answer (score 0):

You were missing some indents.
This version works under Python 3, link [here](https://repl.it/languages/python3)

You need to remember that is function A uses B, then both need to have same indent, in your pasted code, `state_cap_dictionary` was a private function of main, and you wer using it before declaring.

```
# Constant for the number of states to quiz the user on.
NUM_STATES = 5

def main ():
    # Initialize the state_caps dictionary.
    state_caps = state_cap_dictionary()

    # Initial variables to keep count of the number
    # of correct and incorrect answers.
    correct = 0
    incorrect = 0

    #Quiz the user.
    for count in range (NUM_STATES) :
         # Get a random entry from the dictionary.
        state, capital = state_caps.popitem()

        #Quiz the user.
        print ('What is the capital of ', state, '? ')
        response = input()

        # Is the user correct?
        if response.lower() == capital.lower():
            correct += 1
            print ('Correct!')
        else:
            incorrect += 1
            print ('Incorrect.')

        #Display the results                
        print ('Correct responses: ', correct)
        print ('Incorrect answers: ', incorrect)


def state_cap_dictionary ():
      sc = { 'Alabama' : 'Montgomery' ,
          'Alaska' : 'Juneau' ,
          'Arizona' : 'Phoenix' ,
          'Arkansas' : 'Little Rock' ,
          'California' : 'Sacremento' ,
          'Colorado' : 'Denver' ,
          'Conneticut' : 'Hartford' ,
          'Delaware' : 'Dover' ,
          'Florida' : 'Tallahassee' ,
          'Georgia' : 'Atlanta' ,
          'Hawaii' : 'Honolulu' ,
          'Idaho' : 'Boise' ,
          'Illinois' : 'Springfield' ,
          'Indiana' : 'Indianapolis' ,
          'Iowa' : 'Des Moines' ,
          'Kansas' : 'Topeka' ,
          'Kentucky' : 'Frankfurt' ,
          'Lousianna' : 'Baton Rouge' ,
          'Maine' : 'Augusta' ,
          'Maryland' : 'Annapolis' ,
          'Massachusetts' : 'Boston' ,
          'Michigan' : 'Lansing' ,
          'Minnesota' : 'Saint Paul' ,
          'Mississippi' : 'Jackson' ,
          'Missouri' : 'Jefferson City' ,
          'Montana' : 'Helena' ,
          'Nebraska' : 'Lincoln' ,
          'Nevada' : 'Carson City' ,
          'New Hampshire' : 'Concord' ,
          'New Jersey' : 'Trenton' ,
          'New Mexico' : 'Santa Fe' ,
          'New York' : 'Albany' ,
          'North Carolina' : 'Raleigh' ,
          'North Dakota' : 'Bismarck' ,
          'Ohio' : 'Columbus' ,
          'Oklahoma' : 'Oklahoma City' ,
          'Oregon' : 'Salem' ,
          'Pennsylvania' : 'Harrisburg' ,
          'Rhode Island' : 'Providence' ,
          'South Carolina' : 'Columbia' ,
          'South Dakota' : 'Pierre' ,
          'Tennessee' : 'Nashville' ,
          'Texas' : 'Houston' ,
          'Utah' : 'Salt Lake City' ,
          'Vermont' : 'Montpelier' ,
          'Virginia' : 'Richmond' ,
          'Washington' : 'Olympia' ,
          'West Virginia' : 'Charleston' , 
          'Wisconsin' : 'Madison' ,
          'Wyoming' : 'Cheyenne' }
      return sc



main ()
```

Comment: Fixed, thank you for tip, my Python is a bit rusty:)

Comment: Thank you for your help. :D